# Do not show hidden jobs in Windows Task Scheduler by default

Tags: scheduled-tasks, task-manager, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, tasks

In the Windows Task Scheduler on the item "View" when I choose "Show hidden tasks" so that it is turned off, it is not remembered. The next time I run the scheduler, hidden tasks are again shown.

How can I make the task scheduler remember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This choice is not remembered

According to Microsoft, this is by design.

> "Show Hidden Tasks" is ticked by default and can't save your changes
> behavior is set by design. There is no corresponding group policy or
> registry key for this GUI option.
>
> This behavior realized by function defined in tasksche.dll and working
> in Stack. So, when you close the Task scheduler, stack has been
> released and your changes will not be saved.
>
> **If you want to change it, we need to feedback your desire to Microsoft
> through Feedback Hub application.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [Task Scheduler - If it defaults to Show Hidden Tasks, what is the point?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08c4d341-8744-46df-88aa-74b3613e767a/task-scheduler-if-it-defaults-to-show-hidden-tasks-what-is-the-point?forum=win10itprogeneral)